# How to use Rules to fetch domain Whois Data, parse the data and save it to fields?

Tags: 7, rules

For a domain management website I would like to import all Whois data to entity fields. 
A domain is an (ECK) entity, with the fields corresponding with the Whois data.

There are public Whois api's available, such as http://bulkwhoisapi.com/ but I'm not sure which one would best serve the import method I want to use.

How can this be accomplished?

**Note**: My preference is to use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) and not create a custom module.

Comment: My preference is to use Rules and not create a custom module

Comment: OK, much more clear now! Next question: what code (PHP?) do you have available to actually fetch those data using the WhoIs API?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use Rules, you still need to have a connection between Rules and the API. The Rules module by default cannot make API requests (though some contrib module might provide it).

As an alternative I'd like to present to you, the [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds).

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

This module is designed to perform (periodic) requests to external API's and store the data locally. Plus there are a lot of [video tutorials](https://www.google.nl/search?q=drupal+feeds+tutorial) out there to help you with this.

The downside is that feeds by default cannot save to an ECK entity (it can save into a node). The [Feeds ECK Processor](https://www.drupal.org/node/2529072) is currently under review and not yet ready for production. The [Feeds Entity Processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_entity_processor) might work (suggested on the Feeds ECK Processor application page), but this is unconfirmed. Or you can use [Feed Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/feeds_rules?categories=All) to obtain the data with Feeds and then send it to Rules where you can attach it to your entity.

So far this seems possible. The only problem is that feeds does not accept input parameters, so you'd have to create a new feeds importer for every domain...

It is probably not the answer you were hoping for, but perhaps someone else knows how to resolve this last missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at writing a custom module that hooks into `_presave()`, uses the [phpWhois](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois) library to grab the information, and then stores it to the proper fields.

Comment: I'm currently learning Drupal module development so your solution might be a challenge for me. Thats why I throught Rules would make it easier.